# Changing color of select field also changes the color of any options associated with that select field

Tags: javascript, css

I'm setting an invalid select/option field to `color: red;` if it meets an incorrect state, seen here:

```
var gfields = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('gfield');
for(var i = 0; i < gfields.length; i++) {
    var field = gfields[i].getElementsByTagName('select');
    if(field.length) {
        if(field[0].id != e.target.id) {
            var target_value = e.target.value;
            if(field[0].value == e.target.value) {
                e.target.style.color = "Red"; //here
                break;
            } else {
                e.target.style.color = "rgb(68, 68, 68)"; //and here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which works fine, however - doing so sets the color of all of the options within the select box to red too, any idea if there's a means of setting it so only the color of what's displayed in the select box and not the child options of that box is changed?

Cheers in advance.

Comment: define before "e" > `ev=e.target;`

Comment: have you tried simply coloring the options to another color ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out if I did

```
e.target.style.color = "Red";
var options = e.target.childNodes;
for(var x = 0; x < options.length; x++) {
    options[x].style.color = "rgb(68, 68, 68)";
}
```

it fixed my issue, singularly styling each individual option to have the default color, bit 'hacky' but works I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to only color the selectedIndex value from your selectbox:

```
options[gfields.selectedIndex].style.color = "Red" 
//don't know which one is your actual selectbox^^
```